# Jenkins build history wrong order

Tags: jenkins, build

For my Visual Basic project in Jenkins for some reason the build history order is wrong.

In the picture below you can see what i mean:

[image: Build history]

How can I fix this? I've already set a max number of builds to 10 and build 10 new ones but still have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known jenkins 1.633 bug: [jenkins issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-30899).

Downgrading to 1.632 helps. Or upgrading it, even better.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to sort using small icons that appear on mouse hover.[Jenkins History Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9XAh.png)

Comment: It seems I can´t do that. I´m using "Disk usage" and "Config history" plugin as you can see in the picture. Can that be the problem?